# mongo -couldn't connect to a server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb

This is shown when i type `mongod`

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin> mongod
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.446+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.454+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.455+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.458+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":24928,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-E7HDEED"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.458+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.459+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.460+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19041)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.460+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.529+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.531+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=1468M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.735+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1597171009:735319][24928:140720243037424], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 1 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:49.867+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1597171009:866969][24928:140720243037424], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.015+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1597171010:14572][24928:140720243037424], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 1/22016 to 2/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.206+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1597171010:206062][24928:140720243037424], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 1 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.391+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1597171010:390568][24928:140720243037424], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.485+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1597171010:485317][24928:140720243037424], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1145}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.679+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.692+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.820+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.821+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:50.903+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:51.570+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:51.576+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-12T00:06:51.577+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

this is shown in another terminal

````
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin> mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1```
````

Comment: Did you enable your ip address?

Comment: Try to follow (and verify your steps from) the appropriate [MongoDB tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) for Install, start and connect to `mongo` shell.

Comment: which ip address should i enable

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **services**
2. Right Click on **MongoDB Server**
3. Select **Restart**
4. Run the above command **mongo** again